# NotificationListenerService Wearable

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-notification

I am trying to implement a way to detect the notifications that are sent to the android wearable devices.

After googling around, I have found it is not possible to use notificationListenerService on the wearable.

In current implementation, I have implemented the notificationListenerService on the mobile handheld and am using the DataLayer to send the notifications over.

My issue is:

With the notificationListener, it detects everything that appears. Is there a reliable way to detect which notifications will be sent to the wearable? For example, I don't want twilight or other things that are not sent to the wearable to be sent across the dataLayer

Comment: In fact, apps can generate notifications directly on the watch that do not appear on the phone - none of those will be picked up by your approach either.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes this is another issue. To my understanding, I don't believe there is any possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, just filter your `Notifications` in `NotificationListenerService` by [FLAG_LOCAL_ONLY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_LOCAL_ONLY) which is public.
It is set by `.setLocalOnly()` and if it is true notification is not send to Wear device.