# Android Wear - show email on the wear

Tags: android, email, android-notifications, wear-os

First of all, sorry for my english.

I have a project at school and I need to show, on the wear, the number of mails and a little summary of each mail. But my teacher doesn't want to enter the login and the password, which could permit me to connect the mail server. So I thought I can use the notification of the client mail application to count the mail and to show the summary. (But I can only get the mail when the wear is connected and when the application is running)

I can catch the mail notification but I can't send the data to the wear from the NotificationLIstenerService. So, I thought I could catch the notification on the wear but I don't find how to do that.

Have somebody any idea how to do that or have somebody any other idea to the task my teacher is looking for ?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send data to the wear from the NotificationListener service because it is not possible to use notificationListenerService on the wearable and there is no screen for the user to allow this.

Sources:

- [NotificationListenerService Wearable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469863/notificationlistenerservice-wearable)
- [Android Wear: Listen to incoming notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185609/android-wear-listen-to-incoming-notifications)

So for the alternative, you can try to use [Wearable Data Layer API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html), which is part of Google Play service that provides a communication channel for your handheld and wearable apps to send and syncing data. Or you can use the [`NotificationCompat.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) that usually use in creating notification in wearables.

For more information, check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html) on Creating a Notification for Wearables.